# Unknown JSON warning in Visual Studio

Tags: json, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

Given this JSON:

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.24",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../FunctionTest.dll",
  "entryPoint": "FunctionTest.Function1.Run"
}
```

Visual Studio is emitting this warning on line #5:

```
OneOf (Require 1 match, following 14 not matched):
    Exactly 1 match required, but found more than 1
    Value must be one of the following values: "manualTrigger"
    Value must be one of the following values: "timerTrigger"
    Value must be one of the following values: "mobileTable"
    Value must be one of the following values: "documentDB"
    Value must be one of the following values: "table"
    Value must be one of the following values: "notificationHub"
    Value must be one of the following values: "twilioSms"
    Value must be one of the following values: "sendGrid"
    OneOf (Require 1 match, following 2 not matched):
        Value must be one of the following values: "serviceBusTrigger"
        Value must be one of the following values: "serviceBus"
    OneOf (Require 1 match, following 2 not matched):
        Value must be one of the following values: "blobTrigger"
        Value must be one of the following values: "blob"
    OneOf (Require 1 match, following 2 not matched):
        Value must be one of the following values: "eventHubTrigger"
        Value must be one of the following values: "eventHub"
    OneOf (Require 1 match, following 2 not matched):
        Value must be one of the following values: "queueTrigger"
        Value must be one of the following values: "queue"
    Value must be one of the following values: "http" FunctionTest  D:\Dev\Projects\Testing\FunctionTest\FunctionTest\Function1\Function.json
```

I'm not sure what to make of it. I'm coming up empty on Search. It appears it might have something to do with schema validation, but I don't see any reference to a schema in the original JSON.

Could someone point me in the direction of how to identify, decipher and solve this?

Comment: The format of your function.json seems no problem, but the structure of your function is not normal. Maybe that is the key?

Comment: On common, the dll file should be in the bin directory. This is the offcial doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#functions-class-library-project

Comment: Is your second comment the explanation for the first, i.e. the abnormal structure?

Comment: Yes. In fact the format of your function.json is no problem.

Comment: I'm curious about why you felt that it would be easier to identify the line containing the warning without the line numbers. Could you clarify?

Comment: you have describe it in your question. I just make it easy for others to copy the code.

Comment: Maybe you can reinstall the azure develop tools of VS2019. Have you face this problem before?

Comment: I redid this in a new Azure Functions project, and this time the folder hierarchy (and the corresponding JSON) was generated correctly. Previously I'd been following an online sample and manually building these files/folders up, which is why the `bin` folder is missing from the `scriptFile` property (the folder hierarchy is incorrect in the old project). In any case, the new VS-generated JSON also produces the warning—I've decided not to worry about it. Your link to the docs helped me get over this bump, so thank you.

Comment: `you have describe[d] it in your question` OK, sounds good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213706/discussion-between-intexx-and-bowman-zhu).